# How to replace some content with formated content/components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to replace some expressions with correct formatted SVGStringList. For `data.content` has something like `H2O`, which should be displayed as `H<sub>2</sub>O`.
I tried to do that with a simple `replace`, but this seems not to be the react way how to do it.

Also the formatting function should be usable for many replacements. The *H2O* ist just an example.

```
export const formatting = (string) => {
    return string.replace(/H2O/g, 'H<sub>2</sub>O')
}

export default function Content ({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {formatting(data.content)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render html string as actual HTML yuo can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React's replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM.

```js
const formatting = (string) => {
    return string.replace(/H2O/g, 'H<sub>2</sub>O')
}

function Content ({ data }) {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formatting(data) }}></div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Content data="This is H2O"></Content>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Important Note:**

As mentioned in the docs:

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

---

> Also the formatting function should be usable for many replacements.

You will just need to keep updating `formatting` will all replace that you will need like:

```
string
   .replace(/H2O/g, 'H<sub>2</sub>O')
   .replace(/abc/g, 'a<sup>b</sup>c')
   .replace(/(123)/g, '($1)')
   ...so on...
```

Comment: But is there an option not to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML? Do not want to use something "dangerous"...

Comment: In that case, you can use [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser)